# Passing var to php from as3 - My problem is php page is calling twice. I want to call only once

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

This is my php code to check how many time the page is calling.

```
if($_SESSION['test']==''){
            $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
            echo " cond 1 ";
        }
        else {
            echo " cond 2 ";
            $_SESSION['test'] = $_SESSION['test']+1;
        }
        echo " test value = ".$_SESSION['test'];    

        exit;
```

and this is my AS3.0 code to pass the var to php.

```
phpVar.id = phpvars;
phpVar.selectsize = selectedSize;
phpURLr.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
phpURLr.data = phpVar;      
phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
phpLoader.load(phpURLr);    
navigateToURL(phpURLr,"_self");
```

My problem is , I am calling the php page only once, but it is calling the page 2 times.

Pls help me to find out the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phpLoader.load(phpURLr); //first call
navigateToURL(phpURLr,"_self"); //second call
```

In the 1st call you're sending request from AS3. In the 2nd request your sending request from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch:

```
navigateToURL(phpURLr,"_self");
```

This is preferable and also gives you more functionality such as adding event listeners to the URLLoader:

```
phpLoader.load(phpURLr);
```